# Correct way of transaction.rollback() with raise exception in django

Tags: python, django, exception, transactions

I am working with Django 1.7.1 and python 2.7, I am doing some POST requests that requires to be inside a transaction, actually I am using `@transaction.atomic()` decorator that makes the entire function to be inside a transaction.

As far as I know, this decorator is similar to `commit_on_success` and makes a rollback if a database error is raised.

Is it possible to raise a custom exception that makes the transaction to rollback but not using save points? I want to return a HttpResponse when the rollback is done, explaining why the transaction was not completed.

I have this.

```
@transaction.atomic()
def salida_de_almacen(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            folio = request.POST['folio'] #Folio de la orden
            epccoma = request.POST['epc'] #EPCs separados por coma
            if folio is None or epccoma is None:
                return HttpResponse('Datos Incompletos',status=400)
            detalles = ODetalle.objects.filter(orden__folio=folio)
            epcs = epccoma.replace(' ','').split(',')
            inventario = Inventario.objects.filter(epc__in=epcs)
            mal = '' # Items incompletos
            for d in detalles:
                for i in inventario:
                    if i.producto.item == d.producto.item:
                        d.cantidad_entregada+=i.cantidad                        
                        i.delete()
                if d.cantidad_entregada<d.cantidad_ordenada:
                    mal+='%s,' % d.producto.item
            if mal != '':

         >>>>   #raise Exception??  <<<<---- I WANT TO RISE AN EXCEPTION HERE TO ROLLBACK THE TR. 

                return HttpResponse('Items Incompletos: '+mal,status=400)
            for d in detalles:
                d.status=2 #Status completo
                d.save()
            return HttpResponse(serial_folio,status=200) # Todo bien
        except Exception as e:
            return  HttpResponse(e.message,status=500)    
    else:
        ...
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this case - remove decorator, you can wrap part of code in your view:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        # ...
        if mal != '':
            raise IntegrityError

except IntegrityError:
    handle_exception()
```

Any operations attempted inside `atomic` will already have been rolled back safely when handle_exception() is called.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

Comment: Excelent, it works, but, is this the only exception that can make the transaction to rollback? Can I make my own exception and inside the `except` put the `handle_exception()` to make a successful rollback?

Comment: same link - docs  "DatabaseError and its subclasses such as IntegrityError. After such an error, the transaction is broken and Django will perform a rollback at the end of the atomic block."

Comment: if you want manual handling use - `sid = transaction.savepoint()` and `transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)` ... anyway read whole that docs page and it will be clear

Comment: Confirmed on Python 3.7.3 and Django 2.2.2 that the transaction rollbacks for ValueError() too. I think any exception will lead to this and not just DatabaseError. From the same ref doc : "When exiting an atomic block, Django looks at whether it’s exited normally or with an exception to determine whether to commit or roll back. If you catch and handle exceptions inside an atomic block, you may hide from Django the fact that a problem has happened. This can result in unexpected behavior."

Comment: I have a question.. If I have a try except block inside "with transaction.atomic():", will the rollback work?

Comment: @Guilherme Simply if you don't catch IntegrityError then - yes it will work

Answer (score 6):

I have configured my db to `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS'`, so each request is also nested in a transaction.

I was looking for a way to rollback **without** raising an exception. I know, that's not the original question, but for the record the following worked (django 1.11):

```py
from django.db import transaction

def my_view(request):
    # some db interactions
    if it_hit_the_fan:
        transaction.set_rollback(True)
    # return response
```