# Django Transactions ATOMIC_REQUESTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, transactions

I'm really unclear how atomic requests are set in Django. When ATOMIC_REQUESTS is set to True in the DB settings does that mean that all views now run in a transaction? What if I want only certain views to be run in a transaction? Do I then need to explicitly define all the others that are not run in a transaction with a `@transaction.non_atomic_requests` decorator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***When `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` is set to `True` in the DB settings does that mean that all views now run in a transaction?***

Yes. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests):

> Before calling a view function, Django starts a transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django commits the transaction. If the view produces an exception, Django rolls back the transaction.

***Do I then need to explicitly define all the others that are not run in a transaction with a `@transaction.non_atomic_requests` decorator?***

Yes.

> When `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` is enabled, it’s still possible to prevent views from running in a transaction. [The `non_atomic_requests`] decorator will negate the effect of `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` for a given view.

Once you're at the point of deciding on a case-by-case basis where transactions should be used, though, I prefer to not use `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` and just use `transaction.atomic` (whether as a decorator or a context manager) where appropriate. Here's an example from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic):

```
@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes inside a transaction.
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: so if I use `transaction.atomic` on a view without `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` enabled and it will use an atomic transaction on that view? Sorry for explicitly asking, but for me the docs don't give a clear answer to these questions.

Comment: @ip.: Yes, that's true for any function or block of code, including a view.

Comment: If needs be, see my [answer to rollback from inside an atomic block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48680207/777285).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if **`'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True`** is set in **`settings.py`**, all views run in a transaction.

Yes, if **`@transaction.non_atomic_requests` decorator** is set to a view, the view doesn't run in a transaction even if **`'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True`**  is set in **`settings.py`**.

In addition, **Django admin** is run in a transaction by default whether or not **`'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True`** is set in **`settings.py`**.