# Django ORM not storing inside try/except block

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a problem with Django storing objects. When I try to do something inside a try/except block, if everything goes OK, my object is persisted. But if an exception is raised (not because of the object's .save()), nothing is stored.

An example:

```
def my_function(raise_exc):
  MyModel.objects.create(name='name')
  if raise_exc:
    raise Exception()
  return
```

OK case:

```
raise_exc = False
try:
  my_function(raise_exc=raise_exc)
except Exception:
  pass
```

KO case:

```
raise_exc = True
try:
  my_function(raise_exc=raise_exc)
except Exception:
  pass
```

Only in the OK-case, MyModel object is persisted. I can see, by debugging, that in both cases the object is created in RAM memory (MyModel.objects.all() contains it) but not in the database. And if an exception is raised, it looks like it makes a transaction rollback (I am not using transaction blocks. Just in case).

I don't know if this is the desired behavior of the ORM. If it is, what can I do to store objects inside a try block, even if after I save them an exception is raised? (let's say that I shouldn't remove that try/except wrapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour if ATOMIC_REQUESTS are set to TRUE in your database definition in your settings.py

Documentation for atomic requests states:

> Before calling a view function, Django starts a transaction. If the
>   response is produced without problems, Django commits the transaction.
>   If the view produces an exception, Django rolls back the transaction][1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '!',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    }
}
```

**set ATOMIC_REQUESTS to False if you want to keep your database transactions when your code raises an exception.**

Comment: So the problem is not the try/except block, but the whole view function?

Then, @transaction.non_atomic_requests only for that view could solve my problem without changing the settings for the whole project?

Comment: I think the transactions are only rolled back if you have set ATOMIC_REQUESTS to True in your settings as I described above. If that is the case, marking your view with @transaction.non_atomic_requests as you suggested should avoid this rollback. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734306/django-transactions-atomic-requests